# SwiftUI 2.0 disable window's zoom button on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am writing a small App for the Mac..

I need to disable to (Green Button) for full screen.

I am using SwiftUI App not AppKit App Delegate

Cant find how to disable the Full Screen Button for my app.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm.. checked that... could not find a solution. but thanks anyway !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because no one answered with a cleaner SwiftUI only version:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HostingWindowFinder { window in
            window?.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true //this removes the green zoom button
        }
        Text("Hello world")
    }
}

struct HostingWindowFinder: NSViewRepresentable {
    var callback: (NSWindow?) -> ()

    func makeNSView(context: Self.Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak view] in
            self.callback(view?.window)
        }
        return view
    }
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}
```

`HostingWindowFinder` concept taken from https://lostmoa.com/blog/ReadingTheCurrentWindowInANewSwiftUILifecycleApp/

Comment: Wow... Thank you so much for everyone's help.. This worked and is very much appreciated !

Comment: This worked well for me, thank you. It did take up half the screen but I resolved that by setting `.frame(width: 0, height: 0)` on the HostingWindowFinder.

Comment: What about Mac Catalyst?